# Why does react native android app crash frequently?

Tags: android, reactjs, redux, react-native

I have developed a react-native app and deployed it into the play store. I have used react-native-exception-handler to catch exceptions. But, play store reports indicate many crashes.

Will the exceptions caught by react-native-exception-handler be shown as crashes  If NO, then what might be the reasons for these crashes ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has too little detail. Add some code to show exactly how you have used the library in your app. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question one by one:

Will the exceptions caught by react-native-exception-handler be shown as crashes?
*No*

If NO, then what might be the reasons for these crashes?
*There can be many driving factor for crashes, better thing will be to do some more unit testing and have that application tested by some beta tester before shipping it to play-store again.*

Now since you are new to stack-overflow i would suggest you [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).